# How to use gnome-keyring for `ssh-askpass`?

Tags: gnome, ssh, git, keyrings, gnome-keyring

Is there a way to use `gnome-keyring` as an `ssh-askpass` app that is needed by git. The git server can be accessed only by providing a passphrase (doesn't accept ssh keys).